# can't change app icon in flutter its blocks ic_launcher.png and add default android icon from ic_launcher.xml file android library

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, appicon, launcher-icon

[image]

can't change flutter app launcher icon. it loads default android icon from integrated android library. when I try to delete ic_launcher.xml file from the path it deletes, but when I try to reopen the project it recreates the same ic_launcher.xml, and blocking my ic_launcher.png(icon) file in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for changing app icon. [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

Comment: actually i had used this plugin for generating icons and its successfully generated icons , but it doesn't show it on android device.